# Why the HTML5 validator find errors?

Tags: javascript, html

Don't understood !
really ...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>The Storage Age</title>
    <meta name="description" content="The Storage Age">
    <meta name="author" content="The Storage Age">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="./img/favicon.ico">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/main.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js">
        var _gaq = _gaq || [];
        _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-34969704-2']);
        _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
        (function() {
            var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript';
            ga.async = true;
            ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
            var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
            s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
            })();
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
    </header>
        <div id="h">
            <article>
                <h1>&#9679;&#9679;&#9679; The Storage Age &#9679;&#9679;&#9679;</h1>
                <a href="http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.thestorageage.com&amp;doctype=HTML5"><img src="./img/tsa_icon.png" alt="... See you in 2015 AD ..."></a>
                <h2>Electronic archives rock solid</h2>
            </article>
            </div>
    <footer>
    </footer>
    </body>
```

The validator tells "Line 21, Column 11: The text content of element script was not in the required format: Expected space, tab, newline, or slash but found v instead".

Comment: **Did you read the errors?**

Comment: Yes, and didn't understood ...

Comment: What did they say? What don't you understand? Why not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Script tags either use inline code or `src` code, not both at once.

Replace

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js">
        var _gaq = _gaq || [];
        _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-34969704-2']);
        _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
        (function() {
            var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript';
            ga.async = true;
            ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
            var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
            s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
            })();
    </script>
```

with

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        var _gaq = _gaq || [];
        _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-34969704-2']);
        _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
        (function() {
            var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript';
            ga.async = true;
            ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
            var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
            s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
            })();
```

Answer (score 0):

A `<script>` tag can either be external (`src=""`) or internal (code inside the tag).
It can't be both at once.